# Grid Column and row lines are not aligned when columns count increase

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs5

The below is the fiddle link

https://fiddle.sencha.com/local/15332170321551976999/?_dc=1533217071025

Has anyone solved this?

Comment: Please add your code into the question to avoid link rot. See [mcve]

Comment: The fiddle link you provided isn't valid. Please create a new [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) and also everytime you post a question try to include some code too just if the 3rd party fiddle or snippet goes down after years maybe then no one would be able to benefit from your question

Comment: Sure I will add code going forward. Thanks for your response